# Android Facebook App Native Linking not working for All Open Graph Posts

Tags: android, facebook, mobile

My understanding of Facebook Native Deep Linking was that all of my Open Graph activity would link to my native app and not to my web app. I have found that many of the links go to my native app, but some do not.

Links that take me to my app:

1. Post to Wall
2. Open Graph Posts in Activity Feed
3. App Bookmark

Links that take me to my app webpage in chrome:

1. A facebook built Open Graph aggregate on my wall. (I beat 4 levels, then it shows the 4 levels I beat). Note that I haven't built any aggregates for my Open Graph Actions/Objects yet.

Does anyone know why these aggregate links would not be linking to my native app?
Am I doing something wrong?

FYI: I have Forced Stop on the Facebook Application and cleared its data many times, with no luck.

**Edit**

One thing I should point out is that the automatic aggregate can only be seen from a friend. So, if User A posts a bunch of actions into the open graph, then his FB friend User B would be the one seeing the automatic aggregate.

Here are two screenshots taken on my Nexus 7 running Android 4.1.2. Links circled in green take me to my Native Android App. Links circled in red take me to the webbrowser.

Aggregate of "created" action:
[image: Example 1]
<sub>(source: [stiqjoy.com](http://stiqjoy.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/FacebookNotNativeLinkingBug_marks_device-2012-10-17-203036.png))</sub>

Aggregate of "like" action:
[image: Example 2]
<sub>(source: [stiqjoy.com](http://stiqjoy.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/FacebookNotNativeLinkingBug_marks_device-2012-10-17-201424.png))</sub>

Comment: So to be clear: individual actions are deeplinking correctly, but aggregated ones are not?

Comment: I created an aggregation that appears in the timeline. Those links do link to the native app. The problem was the aggregation that facebook built itself. I had for 4 "beat" actions on 4 "levels". It combined those to say "Jared beat 4 Levels" and then showed the 4 levels below. Those are linking to my website instead of my native app.

Comment: I'll be honest, that sounds like a bug. Can you log it with your app ID & steps to reproduce? Thanks

Comment: Alright, I've reported the bug. You can see it here: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/242461415879783. I also added screenshots in the comments. Not sure who can see that though.